# Magento 2: How to overwrite the routes?

Tags: magento2

Magento version: 2.0.0

I copied the Magento_Checkout file to my custom vendor directory and renamed it, but the block and layout are not working for me when i modified some files.

How to overwrite them?

need to change the di.xml?

i just copied it.

Answer (score 5):

In the following explanation I use the `{...}` notation to indicate placeholders you have to substitute with your own values.

Assuming you have created your own `{magedir}/app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}` (or `{magedir}/vendor/{Vendor}/{Module}` if you use composer) - from now on let's call it `{yourmoduledir}` - containing the `{yourmoduledir}/etc/module.xml` activation file you have to:

**1) Define a preference**

Create `{yourmoduledir}/etc/di.xml` with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Controller\{TheActionClassYouWantToOverride}" type="{Vendor}\{Module}\Controller\{TheActionClassThatContainTheOverride}" />
</config>
```

**2) Define your route**

Create `{yourmoduledir}/etc/frontend/routes.xml` with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="{YourRouteId}" frontName="{YourRouteFrontName}">
            <module name="{Vendor}_{Module}" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**3) Create the Action class** (a.k.a. Controller) that contains the override

Create `{yourmoduledir}/Controller/{TheActionClassThatContainTheOverride}.php`

```
<?php
namespace {Vendor}\{Module}\Controller;

class {TheActionClassThatContainTheOverride} extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\{TheActionClassYouWantToOverride}
{
    public function execute()
    {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

4) Update environment

Once all the above configuration and classes file are created, run the following commands from `{magedir}`:

```
# Enable module
bin/magento module:enable {Vendor}_{Module}

# Update config
bin/magento setup:upgrade

# In Production mode you need to generate plugin classes
bin/magento setup:di:compile

# Flush cache
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/routing.html says it's `routes.xml` not `route.xml`

Comment: you are right @ekuusela, thank you, I've edited to fix the typo